# Liquibase - How to run a Java code changeset using SQL Format?

Tags: java, liquibase

With Liquibase XML you can trigger Java code to execute for a change with:

```
    <customChange class="my.java.Class">
        <param name="id" value="2" />
    </customChange>
```

How can you trigger a custom change with Liquibase [SQL Format](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/sql-format.html)?

Comment: None of the answers apply to SQL Format (linked in question). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** You can't.

The supported formats for defining a custom change set are:

1. XML

```
<changeSet id="21" author="nvoxland">
  <customChange class="liquibase.change.custom.ExampleCustomTaskChange">
    <param name="helloTo" value="world"/>
  </customChange>
</changeSet>
```

2. YAML

```
-  changeSet:
     id:  21
     author: nvoxland
     changes:
     -  customChange:  {
"class": "liquibase.change.custom.ExampleCustomTaskChange",
"helloTo": "world" }
```

3. JSON

```
{
  "changeSet": {
    "id": "21",
    "author": "nvoxland",
    "changes": [
      {
        "customChange": {
          "class": "liquibase.change.custom.ExampleCustomTaskChange",
          "helloTo": "world"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Based on https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/custom-change.html

Answer (score 1):

why you don't use `sqlFile` tag to execute custom SQL scripts?
something like this :

```
<changeSet author="me" id="1">
    <sqlFile path="my_script.sql"/>
</changeSet>
```

or even something like this :

```
<changeSet author="me" id="2">
    <sql>
        INSERT INTO my_table (columnAA, columnBB) VALUES ('valueAA', 'valueBB');
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

**update:**
ok sorry, I think you can use the `` tag and set the `customChangeClass` attribute to the fully qualified name of your custom Java class, and don't forget you will need to include the necessary Java classes and dependencies for your custom change in your `Liquibase` classpath!

```
<changeSet author="yourname" id="yourid">
    <comment>Custom change using SQL format</comment>
    <change customChangeClass="com.example.MyCustomChange">
        <param name="id" value="2"/>
    </change>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: This question is about the SQL Format, not XML format: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/sql-format.html

Comment: @bcoughlan please check my answer again!

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeking the SQL changset you can check following link https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/sql-file.html

Changset for xml format using SQL Fromat would as follows:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="sqlFile-example">
     <sqlFile 
        path="my/path/file.sql"
        relativeToChangelogFile="true"
        splitStatements="true"
        stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

the path satrts from the resources file so, that means that `my` in the top changset is a folder under resources folder

---

You can also construct a `JDBCTemplate` object using the `database.getConnection()` in the Java custom change this is handy when you have dynamic data, you want to update DB with

```
public class MyCustomDbChange implements CustomTaskChange {
    @Override
    public void execute(Database database) {
        JdbcConnection jdbcConnection = (JdbcConnection) database.getConnection();
        Connection connection = jdbcConnection.getWrappedConnection();
        SingleConnectionDataSource dataSource = new SingleConnectionDataSource(connection, false);
        JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        //Then you can use JDBCTemplate methods to execute queries
       
        // Example select
        List<Map<String, Object>> map = jdbcTemplate.queryForList("select * from user");

        // Example single update
        jdbcTemplate.update("update user set name='Test' where id='1'");

        // Example batch update using prepared stmt query
        jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(
            "INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (?, ?)",
            new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                @Override
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int idx) throws SQLException {
                    String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                  
                    ps.setString(1, id);
                    ps.setString(2, "dummy name " + id);
                }

                @Override
                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return 100;
                }
            }
        );

       // .... other overridden methods
    }
```